# Efficient method to process 2 variables

Tags: powershell

A lot of my work deals  with 2 csv files (not more). I frequently end up with code like this:

`move-item -path $csv1 -destination "C:\test\Auto-Reports\old-csv"
move-item -path $csv2 -destination "C:\test\Auto-Reports\old-csv"`

While the above works I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to write the above, for example the equivalent of  `move-item -path $csv1 AND $csv2 -destination "C:\test\Auto-Reports\old-csv"` or something to that effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Move-Item`'s `Path` argument is actually a string array, so you can do something like:

```
move-item -path $csv1,$csv2 -destination "C:\test\Auto-Reports\old-csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function moveItems([String[]] $items) {
    ForEach ($item in $items) {
        Move-Item -Path $item -Destination "C:\test\Auto-Reports\old-csv";
    }
}

moveItems($csv1, $csv2);
```

Edit: other answer by ESG is better. But this will show you how to create your own function if needed in future

Comment: While your code technically works, please don't use `;`, unless you want to place multiple commands on a single line, and please don't use pseudo-method syntax to invoke functions:  `moveItems($csv1, $csv2)` should be `moveItems $csv1, $csv2`: no parentheses, whitespace after function name and between arguments (there's only one argument here, the array to pass).